# ¿Se puede crear una función lambda de orden superior en kotlin?

Tags: funciones, kotlin, programación-funcional, lambda

estoy leyendo el tutorial de kotlin en codelads y me surgió esta pregunta, porque en el [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-bootcamp-functions/#6) nos muestran ejemplos pero no uno de este tipo, entonces lo que quiero es algo asi:

```
var dirtyLevel = 20
val waterFilter: (Int) -> Int = { dirty -> dirty / 2}// funcion lambda
val updateDirty: Int = { dirty : Int, operation : (Int) -> Int -> operation(dirty)}// funcion lambda de orden superior
println(waterFilter(dirtyLevel))
println(updateDirty(30,waterFilter))
```

genera este error:

```
error: type mismatch: inferred type is (Int, (Int) -> Int) -> Int but Int was expected
val updateDirty: Int = { dirty : Int, operation : (Int) -> Int -> operation(dirty)}
                       ^
```

tambien lo intente asi `val updateDirty: Int = { (dirty : Int, operation : (Int) -> Int) -> operation(dirty)}` pero genera este error:

```
error: type mismatch: inferred type is (???) -> [ERROR : <ERROR FUNCTION RETURN TYPE>] but Int was expected
val updateDirty: Int = { (dirty : Int, operation : (Int) -> Int) -> operation(dirty)}
```

Comment: ¿Qué resultado esperarías que diese esto: `println(updateDirty(30,waterFilter))`?

Comment: El primer `println()` da 10 porque la funcion **waterFilter** divide en dos el parametro  osea 20/2 el segundo invoca **waterFilter** y le cambia el parametro a 30 osea 30/2 lo que deberia dar 15

Comment: ¿Te valdría esto?: `val updateDirty: (Int, (Int) -> Int) -> Int = { num, operation -> operation(num) }`

Comment: oye si perfecto da **1015**

Comment: Te lo pongo como respuesta entonces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sintaxis sería la siguiente:

```
val updateDirty: (Int, (Int) -> Int) -> Int = { num, operation -> operation(num) }
                  |A|  |-----B-----|    |C|     |D|  |----E--|    |-----F------|
```

Es decir, definimos una función que se llama updateDirty, que acepta dos parámetros, el primero de tipo entero (A), aquí es donde le pasamos el 30, y el segundo parámetro es una función que acepta un parámetro entero y devuelve otro entero (B). Aquí es donde le pasas waterFilter.

Ahora para la implementación de la función, indicamos que tiene dos parámetros: num (D), y y operation (E). Y el contenido de la función (F) lo que hace es llamar a la función que le pasemos por parámetro en nuestro caso waterFilter, pasándole como parámetro el número que le pasemos, en nuestro caso 30.